# JPA OneToOne bi-directional

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have two entities and they are related to each other through a one to one relationship. `User` is the owner of `Balance`. I set Hibernate to automatically create tables and this does not seem to be working. The problem may be caused by other causes but I'd like to make sure that I have the one to one relationship configured correctly first.

Can you please check the following entities and tell me if they are correct?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;   

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "balance_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Balance balance;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "balances")
public class Balance implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "users")
    private User user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct. The value of mappedBy must be the name of the attribute, in the other entity, which is the owner side of the association:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "balance")
```